# Transparency on Windows embedded desktop

Tags: c#, windows, embedded

I am developing an application for Windows Embedded Compact 7. One of my requirements is to program a round button lying on top of other controls (e.g. a `Grid` or a `List`).

It seems to me, that this is not possible in the .Net framework, but desktop icons provide a very good transparency, also on top other icons.

Why is this and can I use this transparency in C# in anyway?

Sorry for missing so much information: I develop in c#, .net 3.5, for two ARM Processors, 500 MHz, 1 GHz, I use Resco Components, and they only support transparency against a Background. They also say, that System.Windows.Forms.Control does not support transparency.

Comment: The icon format was designed to provide transparency effects.  You can get a control with a non-square outline as well, it works very differently.  Unable to guess at the class library you are using, you should take a look at the Control.Region property or the underlying SetWindowRgn() winapi function.  Whether that's supported in your embedded version of Windows is something you'll find out I guess.

Comment: I am working from .net, guess I have no access to winapi functions from here, right, and espacially not to winapi functions that draw on the surface

Comment: Sure you do, pinvoke was made for that.  Highly unlikely you actually need it, nobody can tell from your heavily under-documented question.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers til now. Sorry for my poor info. Is there information missing, that you need to help. Ok, i know I can access winapi via pinvoke, but can this draw on a screen, transparent against controls that are painted by .net and Resco Controls?

Answer (score 0):

Just Copy The Following Code , And Paste It . Just Make One Command Button Or Label Or Anything Else. Background Will Transparent Just Command Buttons Will Be Shown.

```
   Option Explicit
   Private Declare Function CreateRectRgn Lib _
   "gdi32" (ByVal X1 As Long, ByVal Y1 As Long, _
   ByVal X2 As Long, ByVal Y2 As Long) As Long
   Private Declare Function CombineRgn Lib _
   "gdi32" (ByVal hDestRgn As Long, ByVal hSrcRgn1 As Long, _
   ByVal hSrcRgn2 As Long, ByVal nCombineMode As Long) As Long
   Private Declare Function SetWindowRgn Lib _
   "user32" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal hRgn As Long, _
   ByVal bRedraw As Boolean) As Long
   Private Declare Function DeleteObject Lib _
   "gdi32" (ByVal hObject As Long) As Long

   ' Constants used by the CombineRgn function
   Private Const RGN_AND = 1
   Private Const RGN_OR = 2
   Private Const RGN_XOR = 3
   Private Const RGN_DIFF = 4
   Private Const RGN_COPY = 5

   Private Sub Form_Activate()
   Dim rgnForm As Long, rgnCombined As Long
   Dim rgnControl As Long, x As Long
   Dim formWidth As Single, formHeight As Single
   Dim borderWidth As Single, titleHeight As Single
   Dim ctlLeft As Single, ctlTop As Single
   Dim ctlWidth As Single, ctlHeight As Single
   Dim ctl As Control

   ' Calculate the form area
   borderWidth = (Me.Width - Me.ScaleWidth) / 2
   titleHeight = Me.Height - Me.ScaleHeight - borderWidth
   ' Convert to Pixels
   borderWidth = ScaleX(borderWidth, vbTwips, vbPixels)
   titleHeight = ScaleY(titleHeight, vbTwips, vbPixels)
   formWidth = ScaleX(Me.Width, vbTwips, vbPixels)
   formHeight = ScaleY(Me.Height, vbTwips, vbPixels)

   ' Create a region for the whole form
   rgnForm = CreateRectRgn(0, 0, formWidth, formHeight)

   rgnCombined = CreateRectRgn(0, 0, 0, 0)
   ' Make the graphical area transparent by combining the two regions
   x = CombineRgn(rgnCombined, rgnForm, rgnForm, RGN_DIFF)

   ' Make the controls visible
   For Each ctl In Controls
   ' Make the regions of controls whose container is the form visible
   If TypeOf ctl.Container Is Form Then
   ctlLeft = ScaleX(ctl.Left, vbTwips, vbPixels) + borderWidth
   ctlTop = ScaleX(ctl.Top, vbTwips, vbPixels) + titleHeight
   ctlWidth = ScaleX(ctl.Width, vbTwips, vbPixels) + ctlLeft
   ctlHeight = ScaleX(ctl.Height, vbTwips, vbPixels) + ctlTop
   rgnControl = CreateRectRgn(ctlLeft, ctlTop, ctlWidth, ctlHeight)
   x = CombineRgn(rgnCombined, rgnCombined, rgnControl, RGN_OR)
   End If
   Next ctl


   ' Set the clipping area of the window using the resulting region
   SetWindowRgn hWnd, rgnCombined, True
   ' Tidy up
   x = DeleteObject(rgnCombined)
   x = DeleteObject(rgnControl)
   x = DeleteObject(rgnForm)
  End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very very much. I think this is not vb.net, right. Do you know if this will be avalable from c#. .net3.5?

Comment: Thank you very much for your code. Just to make sure, the transparancy, or the round appearance  should work if the Button lies on top of other controls... not only against a Background.